# Пишу телеграмм бота на Python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Начал писать телеграмм бота при запуске команды /survey он выдает мне:
Эхо без состояния или фильтра.
Сообщение:/survey.
На /start и /help реагирует адекватно

```
'main.py'

from loader import bot
import handlers
from utils.set_bot_commands import set_default_commands
from telebot.custom_filters import StateFilter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.add_custom_filter(StateFilter(bot))
    set_default_commands(bot)
    bot.infinity_polling()

Не могу понять в чем дело message_handler прописаны вроде верно:

'survey.py'
from keyboards.reply.contact import request_contact
from loader import bot
from telebot.types import Message
from states.contact_information import UserInfoState


@bot.message_handler(commands=['survey'])
def survey(message: Message) -> None:
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, UserInfoState.name, message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.username} введи свое имя')


@bot.message_handler(state=UserInfoState.name)
def get_name(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.text.isalpha():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Спасибо, записал. Теперь введи свой возраст')
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, UserInfoState.age, message.chat.id)

        with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Имя может содеражать толко буквы')


@bot.message_handler(state=UserInfoState.age)
def get_age(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.text.isdigit():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Спасибо, записал. Теперь введи страну проживания')
        bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, UserInfoState.country, message.chat.id)

        with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
            data['age'] = message.text
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Возраст может быть только числом')


@bot.message_handler(state=UserInfoState.country)
def get_name(message: Message) -> None:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Спасибо, записал. Теперь введи свой город')
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, UserInfoState.city, message.chat.id)

    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['country'] = message.text


@bot.message_handler(state=UserInfoState.city)
def get_city(message: Message) -> None:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                     'Спасибо, записал . Отправь свой номер нажав на кнопку',
                     reply_markup=request_contact())
    bot.set_state(message.from_user.id, UserInfoState.phone_number, message.chat.id)

    with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
        data['city'] = message.text


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'contact'], state=UserInfoState.phone_number)
def get_contact(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.content_type == 'contact':
        with bot.retrieve_data(message.from_user.id, message.chat.id) as data:
            data['phone_number'] = message.contact.phone_number

            text = f'Спасибо за предоставленную информацию ваши данные: \n' \
                   f'Имя - {data["name"]}\n возраст - {data["age"]}\n страна - {data["country"]}' \
                   f'город - {data["city"]}\n номер телефона - {data["phone_number"]}'
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Чтобы отправить контактную информацию нажми на кнопку')
```

Answer (score 0):

В "**init.py**" пакета handlers должен быть такой порядок импортов.

```
from . import custom_handlers
from . import default_heandlers
```